# Referencing RoleProvider in a class library

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider

I'm trying to create a custom role provider in a class library, and for some reason I can't reference `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`.

I have added a reference to `System.Web` in the project, yet still no luck. Is there a reason why I can't do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to reference the assembly `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll`. The `RoleProvider` class is not defined in `System.Web.dll`.

In this cases and when in doubt check the MSDN page for the associated class and at the top of the page you can see in what namespace and assembly it is defined.

For the [`RoleProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) class you have:

> **Namespace:**  System.Web.Security
>
> **Assembly:** System.Web.ApplicationServices (in System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll)